Azure app function - python, overlapping executions overwrite variables
I have a function app in Azure, in which the app gathers row 0 of a cosmosDB and then sends out some emails with data.
When the app function is triggered twice within a short period, I find that content of the first mail is overwritten with data from the 2nd execution, which contains a new row of data.
function.json:
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "queue_name",
      "connection": "connection_env"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "DBfile",
      "databaseName": "db_name",
      "collectionName": "collection_name",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cosmos_db_connection_string",
      "direction": "in",
      "id": "{id}",
      "PartitionKey": "{partitionkey}"
    }
  ]
}


Code:
def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, DBfile: func.DocumentList) -> bool:
    file_raw = DBfile[0].to_json()
    file_json = json.loads(file_raw)
    users = file_json['users']
    for user in users:
        message = {
            "content": {
                "subject": "mail subject",
                "html": json.dumps(file_json['data']),
            },
            "recipients": {
                "to": [{"address": user['emailAddress']}]
            },
            "senderAddress": "<sender@email.com>"
        }

        connection_string_mail = os.getenv("email_connection_string")

        if not connection_string_mail == None:
            email_client = EmailClient.from_connection_string(connection_string_mail)
            email_client.begin_send(message)

As you might be able to deduct from the code, for each user an email is sent. However, when the first trigger is sending emails, the 2nd trigger is triggered and also DBfile[0] is updated I assume. For that reason, in the first execution, the email content is changed I assume.
Could this assumption be correct? And if so, can I somehow either overcome this issue or make the 2nd trigger wait until the first is finished?

Can you share data you are sending from storage queue and payload you have in cosmos db?

How the data is overwritten, can you share some screenshots?

I have the same code alike you in __init__.py file and have below code in function.json file.
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "test-queue",
      "connection": "afrinstore_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "DBfile",
      "databaseName": "TestDB",
      "containerName": "TestCollection",
      "connection": "cosmos_db_connection_string",
      "direction": "in",
      "id": "{id}",
      "PartitionKey": "{id}"
    }
  ]
}

Following points to note-

I am not passing id in payload, rather it is getting generated when creating a new item in cosmos db. I have below payload-

{
    "users": [
        {
            "emailAddress": "First_user_Email_id",
            "name": "User1"
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": "Second_user_Email_id",
            "name": "User2"
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "Message": "Hi, This is First test message",
        "Reason": "First Email"
    }
}

Post creating an item in cosmos db using this payload, below properties are getting amended in the payload along with id which has a unique random value.
{
    "users": [
        {
            "emailAddress": "First_user_Email_id",
            "name": "User1"
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": "Second_user_Email_id",
            "name": "User2"
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "Message": "Hi, This is First test message",
        "Content": "First Email"
    },
    "id": "ab0c2********dc82",
    "_rid": "anEy******AAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/*****==/",
    "_etag": "\"0d01e3*****000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1716892242
}


My queue trigger function is getting triggered, when I am sending below message from storage queue and email is being sent successfully with correct content.

{
  "id": "ab0c2********dc82"
}


If your function is getting trigger twice that means you are sending the id value of 2nd cosmos db item in queue message which would be unique and it would fetch the email content present in the 2nd item.
I have tested it and it worked as expected. I have two messages in storage queue as shown below.


While executing the function, getting expected response.


